# Prevent bootstrap Datetime Picker close on select time up and down button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the tried **dp.change** to hide the datetime picker on change event of date and time but it should not get close on time up and down button.

I properly Used each and every library required for datetime Picker.
I studied the doc of https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ but nothing is helpful for me.

this is my HTML code:

```
 <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 center-block">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-12"> Date ( YYYY-MM-DD )</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 no-padding">
                                        <label>Start Date</label>
                                    </div>
                                     -->
                                     <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                                        <label class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 text-center noPadding"><b>From:</b></label>
                                     <div class='input-group date col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-12' id='startDate'>

                                        <input type='text' class="form-control " placeholder="Start Date" id="startDateInput"/>
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 no-padding">
                                        <label>End Date</label>
                                    </div> -->
                                    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                                         <label class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 text-center noPadding"><b>To:</b></label>
                                    <div class="input-group date col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-12" id='endDate'  >
                                        <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="End Date" id="endDateInput" />
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
```

This is intialization of datetime picker

```
 $('#startDate').datetimepicker({
         format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
         collapse:false,
         sideBySide:true,
         useCurrent:false,
         showClose:true,
        });

     $('#endDate').datetimepicker({
         format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
         collapse:false,
         sideBySide:true,
         useCurrent:false,
         showClose:true,
     });
```

This is event to hide the datetime picker

```
$("#startDate").on("dp.change", function (e) {
          $('#startDate , #endDate').data("DateTimePicker").hide();
   });

   $("#endDate").on("dp.change", function (e) {
          $('#endDate').data("DateTimePicker").hide();
   });
```

Now My question is datetime picker should not get close on timepicker up and down button.
I have tried to get that from where even is getting fired but that is also not giving me anything.

This is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eradi_singh/byx1couq/43/) where any on  wish to update for he solution

Comment: If you remove the "event to hide the datetime picker" code it works as you want.

Comment: remove .hide() from $('#startDate , #endDate').data("DateTimePicker").hide(); line of code

Comment: @PrakashThete if i will remove hide the it will not hide the datetimepicker even if i will click on date . i want it should get hide on click of date and time selection not on increment of time. so i think you will get moto of question

Comment: @Kabali I think you are missing the point here If as you said on click of date / time it has to hide then when user wants to select some date and time he has to open the datetime picker 2-3 times(as it will get closed on click of date/time) for one operation. 
It may be your application need but I will suggest to go with default approach as given by "bootstarp datetimepicker"

Comment: @PrakashThete User can select the date once but he have to increment the time bro and if it will hide again he needs to on the datetime picker ..but date can be selected in onetime

Answer (score 1):

> Now My question is datetime picker should not get close on timepicker up and down button.

To achive this you need to handle theese buttons so that they can be ignored from the dp.change event:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#startDate').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
    collapse:false,
    sideBySide:true,
    useCurrent:false,
    showClose:true
  });

  $('#endDate').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
    collapse:false,
    sideBySide:true,
    useCurrent:false,
    showClose:true
  });


  $("#startDate, #endDate").on("dp.show", function (e) {
    $('table.table-condensed a.btn').on('click', function(e) {
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      var selector = 'seconds';
      var op = '+';
      switch ($(this).attr('data-action')) {
        case "incrementSeconds":
          break;
        case "incrementMinutes":
          selector = 'minutes';
          break;
        case "incrementHours":
          selector = 'hours';
          break;
        case "decrementHours":
          op = '-';
          selector = 'hours';
          break;
        case "decrementMinutes":
          op = '-';
          selector = 'minutes';
          break;
        case "decrementSeconds":
          op = '-';
          selector = 'seconds';
          break;
      }
      var cachedEle = $(this).closest('table.table-condensed').find('span[data-time-component="' + selector + '"]');
      var resultValue = ((op == '+') ? +cachedEle.text() + 1 : (+cachedEle.text() == 0) ? 59 : +cachedEle.text() - 1) % 60;
      cachedEle.text( (resultValue < 10) ? '0' + resultValue : resultValue );
      var originalTargetId = $(this).closest('#startDate, #endDate').attr('id');
      var seconds = $(this).closest('table.table-condensed').find('span[data-time-component="seconds"]').text();
      var minutes = $(this).closest('table.table-condensed').find('span[data-time-component="minutes"]').text();
      var hours = $(this).closest('table.table-condensed').find('span[data-time-component="hours"]').text();

      $('#' + originalTargetId).attr('changedHHMMSS', hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds);

      $('#' + originalTargetId).trigger("dp.change", {'originalTargetId': originalTargetId, 'hours': hours, 'minutes': minutes, 'seconds': seconds})
    });
  });

  $("#startDate, #endDate").on("dp.hide", function (e) {
    $('table.table-condensed a.btn').off('click');
  });

  $("#startDate, #endDate").on("dp.change", function (e, originalTargetId) {
    if (originalTargetId === undefined) {
      var changedHHMMSS = $(this).attr('changedHHMMSS');
      $(this).removeAttr('changedHHMMSS');
      if (changedHHMMSS !== undefined) {
        var inputVal = $(this).children('input').val();
        $(this).children('input').val(inputVal.substring(0, inputVal.length - changedHHMMSS.length) + changedHHMMSS);
      }
      $(this).data("DateTimePicker").hide();
    } else {
      if (originalTargetId instanceof Object && 'originalTargetId' in originalTargetId) {
        console.log('Discard events coming from hh:mm:ss: ' + originalTargetId.originalTargetId);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/d004434a5ff76e7b97c8b07c01f34ca69e635d97/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/d004434a5ff76e7b97c8b07c01f34ca69e635d97/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>


<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 center-block">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 reportCriteriaHead">
        <div class="reportCriteriaTitle col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-12"> Date ( YYYY-MM-DD )</div>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 no-padding">
           <label>Start Date</label>
       </div>
 -->
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <label class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 text-center noPadding linehgt"><b>From:</b></label>
        <div class='input-group date col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-12 selectSumary ' id='startDate'>

            <input type='text' class="form-control " placeholder="Start Date" id="startDateInput"/>
                      <span class="input-group-addon">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                      </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 no-padding">
            <label>End Date</label>
        </div> -->
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <label class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 text-center noPadding linehgt"><b>To:</b></label>
        <div class="input-group date col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-12 selectSumary " id='endDate' >
            <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="End Date" id="endDateInput" />
                     <span class="input-group-addon">
                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                     </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have tried in right way but now onclick of up and down button time is not getting incremented so its not that worth for me sorry.

Comment: @Kabali Snippet updated. Let me know if you accept it and upvote.

Comment: @gaetonM now also there is bug if you are changing the time from up down button its not reflecting in the input type click two three time you will came to know ..by the way thanks for your effort i already solved this in some other manner.

Comment: Thanks to you. In any case I will take a look.

Comment: @Kabali Two fixes: reset global attribute and minus operation on HH:MM:SS. Bye, annd thanks again